# getting same value for href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in `jQuery` ,I am trying to get the value of href attribute when the user clicks on a link but I am getting same values for href attributes. 
here is my html code

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1" >Sign In</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#2">Brand</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#3">Distributor Brand</a>
        </li>
        <li class="language"> <a href="#4">English</a>

            <ul id="language-select">
                <li><a href="#5">Spanish</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#6">French</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and js

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("a").click(function(){            
        var value=$(".container").find("a").attr("href");            
        alert("hello------>  "+value);
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/suraj0750/rmbvo9oh/1/

Comment: you need `var  value=$(this).attr("href");`

Comment: down voting makes no sence

Comment: Why is this Question voted down? It is clearly formulated and even has a fiddle...

Comment: might be because a simple search for [jquery get clicked elements href](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=jquery%20get%20clicked%20elements%20href) would have given the answer - anyway the downvote was not from me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this :-

```
 var  value=$(this).attr("href");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rmbvo9oh/2/)

Comment: +1 Yup - that is the way to go, using the `this` keyword references the actual `a` tag that was clicked.

Comment: what Mohit has expalined is the simplest and the best answer

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, when you bind an event to an element, the `this` variable is being available (of course depending on the element and event). So, when you click an element and bind a function, within that function scope the clicked element is referenced as `this`. Writing `$(this)` you make a jQuery object out of it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a").click(function(){

    var value = $(this).attr("href");

    alert("hello------>  " + value);
  });


});
```